# How would I match a jumbled word from one array to it's correct spelling word in another array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Say I have two arrays of strings, one with words that have had their letters messed up, and the other array with the correct-spelling words (ex. aabann in the 1st array to match up with banana in the second array.)

Other than the bruteforce method which would compare every permutation of the jumbled word to every word in the correct word array, what would be a beginner's method for doing this using rather simple code?

Comment: Monte Carlo the string (shuffle it?) and search for that string in your array of correct words. if found, you shuffled it right, otherwise shuffle again. this assumes that at least one permutation of the jumbled string is a valid string in the correct array

Comment: The issue with this method is that it's a 'bruteforce' issue, it will possibly compare a vast amount of permutations taking much, much more time than needed. While it is a solution, i'm looking for an simple, efficient one.

Comment: No need for taking permutation , Counting the no of occurences of each character will provide you that jumbled character can make up the original word or not !

Comment: Are both arrays coming as parameters, or you got one with correct spelling  and then you create second messed up version?

Comment: They are separate string arrays taken from separate text files. I'm still a beginner so I don't know if that was the answer you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks - that is a good answer. I have posted my proposal and code should be provided on request.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    package com.se;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JumbledWords {

    public void doTask(){

        String[] words = { "apple", "banana", "kiwi", "Water", "Football", 
                "Ocean", "Game", "Fear", "Frost", "Crocodile", 
                "Rabbit", "Road", "Blockbuster", "Cruise", "Light", "aba"};


        String[] jumbledWords = { "aabann", "wiki", "plepa", "Water", "Football", 
                "ncaOe", "maGe", "Frae", "tFors", "rCoodciel", 
                "baRitb", "doRa", "btBulockser", "urCise", "itLgh", "bab"};

        Map<String, String> foundWords = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for(String jwItem : jumbledWords){

            char[] wordChars = jwItem.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(wordChars);

            for(String w : words){
                char[] jwChars = w.toCharArray();
                Arrays.sort(jwChars);

                String str1 = new String(wordChars);
                String str2 = new String(jwChars);

                if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)){
                    foundWords.put(w, jwItem);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(foundWords);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date date1 = new Date();


        JumbledWords jw = new JumbledWords();
        jw.doTask();

        Date date2 = new Date();
        System.out.println("Time Taken: " + (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()));
    }
}
```

This is case sensitive though.

**UPDATE**

Ok for case insensitive match I have put `word = word.toLowerCase();` in the getCharacterList method.

**UPDATE 2**

Removed the conversion to ArrayList, applied code to the arrays directly.

**UPDATE 3**

The previous code had a little bug. Now the code is corrected. It is more compact now.

Comment: Can you add comment what does it do?

Comment: It is simply looping through both arrays, breaking each string into array of individual characters and then using the List class containsAll method to check whether all elements of one list (composed of characters) are present in the other list. If yes then it means the the characters in the jumbled word forms the correct word.

Comment: @MaxZoom I hope you understand it now fully.

Comment: Similar to my solution, but less optimized.

Comment: How? Any proof? I will appreciate.

Comment: No it is not doing any arraylist conversions. See my second update.

Comment: Not these observations do not make sense. It is doing everything very efficiently and more efficiently then your code as far as I have checked from wrapping up the two codes inside date stamps. :)

Comment: Looks better now but still has that bug:  it will match word `aba` to the word `bab`

Comment: That is exactly what it should do. Anyways thanks for your time. Rather than proving my code inefficient come up with a better solution that takes little time than mine and then point to me I will be happier to learn. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, word `aba` (a2b1) should never match word `bab` (a1b2) -> this is a BUG

Comment: Ok i see what u r saying. That can b taken care off easily too. I will share corrected one.

Comment: @MaxZoom Ok code is now updated. Now that bug is not there. Now you can compare the time efficiency of the two codes.

Comment: No I am not following your solution. You said my code is not optimized and I am still wondering how can you claim when actually your code is taking more time than mine. Still my code is running faster than yours.

Answer (score 1):

First try I would make is using the levenshtein distance algorithm to find the lowest amount of changes between to index ;)

You can find an impl. of that algorith in apache commons lang StringUtils
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/index.html

If that is not enough you can do stuff like this.

Use a phonetic algorithm like metaphor or soundex to produce phonetic string values of both array, than use levenshtein to compare them.
The phonetik algorithm will shorten the string and bringing them in a more phonetic sound speech thingi, where the possibility is increased that the levenshtein distance is lower.

Thats how spellcheckers and so on are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the below strategy assuming that my assumption is correct.

My assumption: Exactly one string in the second array matches with an entry in first array other wise there would be multiple answers.

Strategy:
For both the arrays and for each word in it, find the exact characters/literals used with their count.
Then compare between both the arrays and check which of the two exactly match in terms in characters with their count.

That would give the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would transform every String to a Word that contains the whole word and a Map of every character and it counter, and then just compare it, the example should be something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List<Word> messed = new ArrayList<Word>();
        messed.add(new Word("aabann"));
        messed.add(new Word("mosue"));
        messed.add(new Word("atomich"));

        List<Word> correct = new ArrayList<Word>();
        correct.add(new Word("mouse"));
        messed.add(new Word("athomic"));
        correct.add(new Word("banana"));

        for (Word messedWord : messed) {
            System.out.println(messedWord.getOriginalWord());
            for (Word correctWord : correct) {
                if (correctWord.compareTo(messedWord) == 0) {
                    System.out.println(correctWord.getOriginalWord());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Word implements Comparable<Word> {

    Map<String, Integer> characters;

    String originalWord;

    public Word(String originalWord) {
        this.originalWord = originalWord;

        characters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < originalWord.length(); i++) {
            String key = String.valueOf(originalWord.charAt(i));
            Integer counter = characters.get(key);
            if (counter == null) {
                characters.put(key, 1);
            } else {
                characters.put(key, counter.intValue() + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getCharacters () {
        return characters;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo (Word arg0) {
        if (arg0.getCharacters().size() != this.getCharacters().size()) {
            return -1;
        }
        for (String character : this.getCharacters().keySet()) {
            if (this.getCharacters().get(character).intValue() != arg0
                    .getCharacters().get(character).intValue()) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public String getOriginalWord () {
        return originalWord;
    }
}
```

And the output is each messed word and it's correct spelling:

```
aabann
banana
mosue
mouse
atomich
athomic
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution to compare strings based on their keys.
The key would be generated based on the characters and their count in a word.
For example:

```
word: banana -> key: a3b1n2
word: aabann -> key: a3b1n2
```

If the keys match then do the strings.
Below is the Java code to support above approach.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class WordCompare
{
    public static String getKey(String str) {
      char[] arr = str.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
      Arrays.sort(arr);
      return new String(arr);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       String[] correct = { "apple", "banana", "kiwi", "Abba"};
       String[] mixedup = { "aabann", "wiki", "plepa", "Baba"};

       Map<String, String> lookup = new HashMap<>(correct.length);
       for (String str : correct) {
         lookup.put(getKey(str), str);
       }

       for (String mix : mixedup) {
         String key = getKey(mix);
         String match = lookup.get(key);
         System.out.format("%s = %s\n", mix, match);
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes please share, it will be good to see a different solution.

Comment: I have added the entry level Java code (see above). More advance code with Regular Expression could also be use but that would be too much for starters.

Comment: If you are talking about time efficiency then wrap your code in main method between

this
Date date1 = new Date();

and this
Date date2 = new Date();
System.out.println("Time Taken: " + (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()));

and compare with mine.

Comment: Optimize your code so that it takes less time than mine and then share. I will be happy to look.

Comment: Your code does not run faster then mine. If you remove the print statements  you will see similar time.

Comment: I am not impressed with your code, it is taking too much time to do trivial task.

Comment: For your satisfaction I have added that one print line to my code as well but still my code is taking less time than yours. Almost half time. Check this link yourself. http://ideone.com/8k7s1p

Comment: Lol now u got it right taking hints from my code. Goodluck. Not interested in optimizing my code  neither tried to do so once. ;)